# Do the singularity conditions for black holes hold with a cosmological constant?

Tags: cosmology

If lambda is extremely small what happens under a spherically symmetric metric in the black hole limit. I am not suggesting it is repulsive of course, just does lambda still exist in these formal limits

Answer (score 0):

The geometry of a spherically symmetric mass in a de Sitter background is described by the [de Sitter-Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric).

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1 - \frac{2M}{r} - \frac{\Lambda r^2}{3}\right) dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{\left(1 - \frac{2M}{r} - \frac{\Lambda r^2}{3}\right)} + r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 $$

where $M$ is the mass of the object and $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant. The locations of the two horizons are given by setting:

$$ 1 - \frac{2M}{r} - \frac{\Lambda r^2}{3} = 0 $$

Setting $\Lambda=0$ gives us the usual Schwarzschild horizon at $2M$ and setting $M=0$ gives us the usual de sitter cosmological horizon at $\sqrt{3/\Lambda}$.

With non-zero $M$ and $\Lambda$ the two horizons move together slightly.

Comment: Thanks. Would keeping lambda non zero prevent a singularity from forming? Well at least in a non quantum picture

Comment: @G.W.Kentwell: you need to be a bit more precise about what you are asking. For example if you are considering the collapse of an interstellar dust cloud to form a black hole then a large enough CC will pull the cloud apart so it never collapses. However if you make some cloud of matter dense enough then it will always collapse to a black hole with a singularity regardless of the cosmological constant.

Comment: Yes. You are right. What I am really asking is does a finite cosmological constant stop a formal black hole singularity from forming. It may well be incredibly small but finite nevertheless. One can argue that the Planck length comes into play but here in general relativity quantum effects do not enter.